# systemd-networkd seems to ignore .link files

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, systemd-networkd

I'm using Archlinux on a Raspberry Pi 3. The wireless adapter was working with systemd-networkd and wpa_supplicant. I named the device to "wlan0" using a 00-wlan0.link file containing:

```
[Match]
MacAddress=b8:27:eb:20:a4:a5

[Link]
Name=wlan0
```

After trying to bridge the wired and the wireless adapter which resulted in neither of one working anymore, I deleted all files from /etc/systemd/network except 00-lan0.link and lan0.network which give a static IP to my wired adapter so I can access the machine via cable.
No I observe that after rebooting, the wireless interface's name still is wlan0, although the .link file giving it that name is not in place anymore. Furthermore, if I add another .link file trying to give the interface a new name (wlan1), this is ignored and the device still shows up under the name wlan0. What could cause this and how can you debug this problem?

Comment: From [systemd.link man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html), `The first (in lexical order) of the link files that matches a given device is applied`. So, if you add another link file for the same device, one of them is ignored. Also, you should assign static IPs via your router, since you never know who might lease the IP you want while your the Raspberry PI is shutdown. (Had to learn this the hard way.)

Comment: @Munir As I described, I deleted the first link file, so at least in the /etc/systemd/network folder there is nothing to mask my new link file.

Comment: Ahh..sorry. Misunderstood what you did there.

Answer (score 2):

Systemd-networkd respects files in multiple locations, namely, `/etc/systemd/network`, `/run/systemd/network` and finally `/lib/systemd/network`. If a file whose base name is lexically before your file, it takes precedence, even if its location doesn't prevail. You should find out if such file exists and delete it. `networkctl status <iface>` will show information about the interface. Look for the line about `Link File`.

Answer (score 1):

`systemd-networkd` ignores `.link` files, indeed. This is expected. What interprets `.link` files is called `systemd-udevd`. You can easily check this by introducing (e.g.) a nonexistent option into a configuration file and then restarting the particular daemon. You'll see that errors in `.network` files will be reported by `systemd-networkd` whereas errors in `.link` files will be reported by `systemd-udevd`.